# Qual a melhor prática para instanciar uma classe em Java?

Tags: java, android

Visando o desempenho, como devo instanciar um objeto (ex um DatabaseHandler) para ser usado nos Fragmentos. Devo instanciar-las na activity e passar via método construtor aos Fragmentos ou devo instanciar-las em cada Fragmento?

Comment: Classes não são chamadas.

Comment: OK obrigado vou reformular a pergunta.

Comment: Pelo que eu aprendi até agora de JAVA Android tudo q você escreve de código é compilado ara o bitecode executável da virtual machine do java.
Sendo assim mesmo que você chame o objeto varias vezes o consumo de memória é basicamente o mesmo.
O que existe são boas práticas de escrita de código tudo determina sua logica e finalidade.
No meu caso eu crio a classe separada e quando preciso utiliza-la ou instancio ela ou utilizo como uma interface. Alem de mais simples tudo fica separado no seu devido lugar.

Comment: tanto faz. o importante é o objeto que vai ser utilizado várias vezes não ser do tipo estático.

Comment: O ideal é que seja instanciada em cada Fragment mesmo. Você tentou algum código já? Está tendo algum tipo de erro?

Comment: @Leonardo Dias já fiz funcionar com as duas formas. A dúvida é qual é a melhor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para saber qual a melhor alternativa, você precisaria saber se o seu objeto será utilizado por todos os fragmentos.

Em caso afirmativo, seria interessante criar uma abstração comum a todos os fragmentos (e.g. `AbstractFragment`) que implementaria um construtor padrão para inicializar esse objeto como um atributo dessa abstração, e torná-lo acessível a todos os fragmentos filhos. Assim você não repete a declaração do objeto em todos os fragmentos. Nessa abordagem, o estado do objeto pode variar de fragmento para a fragmento (i.e. não é um atributo `static`) mas a existência dele é comum a todos.

Caso o objeto pertença apenas a fragmentos específicos, o ideal é declará-lo dentro do escopo do fragmento mesmo. Nessa abordagem você o adicionaria como atributo inicializado pelo construtor ou parâmetro de um método dependendo do uso do mesmo dentro do fragmento. Se ele for bastante usado, coloca como atributo, caso contrário, como parâmetro do método que o utilizará. Assim você mantém suas classes coesas.